# How would I put a paragraph in between lists?

Tags: html

How would I put a paragraph in between lists as it is not allowed?

Example of code is below:

```
<ol>
   <li>One</li>
     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
   <li>Two</li>
     <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ol>
      <li>One
        <p>Lorem ipsum carrots enhanced rebates. The very kind of them to the blandishments of the Great, which he may otherwise be able to. Takes pleasure! For some, rejecting some himself, of the blessed, but debt at his deserted the general's, the architect of life, and extremely difficult for those who have some pain, but the advantage of any of them!</p>
      </li>
      <li>Two
        <p>Lorem ipsum carrots enhanced rebates. The very kind of them to the blandishments of the Great, which he may otherwise be able to. Takes pleasure! For some, rejecting some himself, of the blessed, but debt at his deserted the general's, the architect of life, and extremely difficult for those who have some pain, but the advantage of any of them!</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum carrots enhanced rebates. The very kind of them to the blandishments of the Great, which he may otherwise be able to. Takes pleasure! For some, rejecting some himself, of the blessed, but debt at his deserted the general's, the architect of life, and extremely difficult for those who have some pain, but the advantage of any of them!  
        </p>
        <p>
           Lorem ipsum carrots enhanced rebates. The very kind of them to the blandishments of the Great, which he may otherwise be able to. Takes pleasure! For some, rejecting some himself, of the blessed, but debt at his deserted the general's, the architect of life, and extremely difficult for those who have some pain, but the advantage of any of them!  
        </p>
      </li>
   </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can include paragraphs to `li` tags:

```
<ol>
   <li>
     One
     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
   </li>
   <li>
     Two
     <p>Paragraph 2</p>
   </li>
</ol>
```